# How to check a type for a nested template?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'd like to create a type trait which detects the existence of a nested class template within some other type of interest.

For example, suppose I want to create the type trait `has_foo`, which detects the presence of a nested template of one parameter named `foo` within some type `T`:

```
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
struct has_foo
{
  // XXX what goes here?
};

struct with_foo
{
  template<class T> struct foo {};
};

struct without_foo {};

int main()
{
  assert(has_foo<with_foo>::value);
  assert(!has_foo<without_foo>::value);

  return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to implement `has_foo`?

Comment: Is `foo` only taking types? Or is it an arbitrary template?

Comment: `foo` only takes a single type parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <template<class> class> using void_templ = void;

template <typename, typename=void> struct has_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_foo<T, void_templ<T::template foo>>  : std::true_type {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c99da9cc17010fb0). GCC will allow any type here; That is a bug. To fix that make `void_templ` a class template

```
template <template<class> class>
struct void_templ {using type = void;};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbfc77b344e60a32).

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure about this being a bug. Alias templates cannot be specialized, so if one is defined to be always `void`... however, Clang disagrees. And still, there will be an error when substituting the deduced argument.

Comment: [CWG 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558). Also, since `void_t` taking a type parameter pack has been voted into the standard, might want to change it to a different name; and also perhaps change the signature to take exactly one parameter.

Comment: @T.C. I knew there was a CWG issue :-). And I didn't know about `void_t`, will change that.

Comment: Because if you want to detect the presence of a template taking exactly one type parameter, then you don't want to match a template taking two type parameters :)...OTOH, maybe it makes more sense to check the well-formed-ness of `T::template foo<int>`, to account for e.g., default arguments...

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, I didn't properly read the question :D. `T::template foo<int>` might be ill-formed when default arguments use SFINAE.. (which will cause the matching of the partial specialization to hard-error) so there really is no point considering those, is there?

Comment: Hmm, interesting, GCC hard errors for `T::template foo<int>` when `foo` either SFINAEs out `int` or when it takes two parameters; Clang simply SFINAEs for both of these cases. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c11a15019ec7427b